# Are hyperoperators primitive recursive?

Tags: reference-request, recursion, hyperoperation

I apologize if this question is too basic. I have read that the Ackerman function is the first example of a computable but NOT primitive recursive function. Hyperoperators seem to be closely related to these functions, but I am not sure if they still keep the property of being NOT primitive recursive. My intuition is that they are, but I am not sure. Any textbook or references to read to get a better understanding of this will be very appreciated (and a straight response too!).

NOTE: I read this related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96483/ackermann-function-primitive-recursive), but it doesnt help me.

Comment: Each given hyperoperation can be implemented by a bounded loop of the previous hyperoperation.

Comment: straight answer welcomed!!! (so, if I got it right, any of them can be computed using a do-loop?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I have understood well yes.

Because if follow from the definiton of [hyperoperators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation) definition.

$H_0(a,b):=S(b)$

is the successor function, and every hyperoperation is defined recursively from the successor function:

(recursive definition of $H_{n+1}$ using $H_n$)

$i)$ $H_{n+1}(a,0):=a_{n+1}$

$ii)$ $H_{n+1}(a,b+1):=H_n(a,H_{n+1}(a,b))$

Here $a_{n+1}$ is the initial value of the function when the argument is $0$ and in the case of hyporoperators we have that

$a_ {n+1}:=
\begin{cases}
a,  & \text{if $n=0$} \\
0, & \text{if $n=1$ }  \\
1, & \text{if $n\gt 1$ }  \\
\end{cases}$

Since $H_0(a,b)=S(b)$ is the successor funtion and is basic primitive rucursive funtion, we have that all the hyperoperations (that are defined from $H_0(a,b)=S(b)$) are [Primitve recursive functions](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aPrimitive_Recursive_Function).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that although each hyperoperation $H_n:\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ **is** primitive recursive, the function $H: \mathbb{N}^3 \to \mathbb{N}: (n,x,y) \mapsto H_n(x,y)$ is **not** primitive recursive. A simple proof of this is skecthed in [Introduction to Computability Theory](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.76.3873&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Zucker & Pretorius.

Comment: Of course @r.e.s. , this remark link us to the Ackermann-like functions topic.

Answer (score 4):

(Elaborating on my comment to the accepted answer ...)

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the $n$th [hyperoperation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation) 
$$H_n: \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}: (x,y) \mapsto H_n(x,y)$$ 
**is** primitive recursive.

However, for any integer constant $c\ge 2$, the following functions are **not** primitive recursive:

$$\begin{align}
f_c&: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}: n \mapsto H_n(c,n)\\
g_c&: \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}: (n,y) \mapsto H_n(c,y)\\
h&: \mathbb{N}^3 \to \mathbb{N}: (n,x,y) \mapsto H_n(x,y).
\end{align}$$

When $n$ is included as an argument, the function grows too fast to be primitive recursive.

E.g., $x\uparrow^n y\ $ **is** primitive recursive *as a function of $(x,y)$ for fixed $n$*, but it is **not** primitive recursive *as a function of $(n,y)$ for fixed $x\ge 2$*.

Essentially these results are proved in Chapter 13 of  "Computability, Complexity, and Languages" (1983) by Davis & Weyuker, and also sketched in [Introduction to Computability Theory](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.76.3873&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Zucker & Pretorius.