# Is it true that Ackermann's function cannot be implemented without recursion?

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, ackermann-function

Yesterday I got sucked into a bingewatch of Computerphile's and Numberphile's videos on youtube. In particular I ended up watching some on Ackermann's function. While I knew already this function (and the effect it can have on mathematicians if [called with Graham's number as the arguments](https://xkcd.com/207/)), I did not know that it was designed to be computable only through recursion (or, at least, that is what [the video I watched](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7sm9dzFtEI) claims).

The thing is that in a [follow-up video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNACwX-O5lk) is shown that you can the results can be computed through exponentiation, and [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Table_of_values) says that it is really easy to write doen the result using Knuth's up-arrow notation.

So here's lie my problem: [stretching for a moment the imagination and assuming that all integers are representable into a computer, avoiding the risk of overflows, that are outside the scope of this question]
if it can be represented through Knuth's up-arrow notation, can't a program that does not use recursion be written to compute the value?

Is it any different for the original Ackermann's function? (the one that Wikipedia says it has 3 arguments instead of 2)

Comment: How would you implement the up-arrow operation without recursion?

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96483/ackermann-function-primitive-recursive , whose top answer gives a pretty good characterization of 'primitive recursive' that might offer an answer to your question.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki oh, thanks, I missed that one. flagged as duplicate.